# Understanding glXCreateContextAttribsARB attributes setup

Tags: c++, linux, opengl

I am creating OpenGL 4.2 context manually for Linux.

I create an arrays of context attributes like this:

```
    int context_attribs[] = {
        GLX_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 4,
        GLX_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 2,
        GLX_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB, GLX_CONTEXT_DEBUG_BIT_ARB,
        GLX_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB, GLX_CONTEXT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE_BIT_ARB,
        None
    };
```

Then I pass it into [glXCreateContextAttribsARB](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/glx_create_context.txt)() .The context is created all right but I have a couple of question regarding the attribute flags.
For example , for GLX_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB based on the docs I have 2 options :

```
    GLX_CONTEXT_DEBUG_BIT_ARB       0x0001
GLX_CONTEXT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE_BIT_ARB  0x0002
```

If I select the first one ,does it mean OpenGL runs in debug mode?If yes then if I set this flag to the second option does it mean I am not going to be able to use fixed functionality?
If yes then how do I set "non debug" context but in compatibility profile mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All flags are orthogonal. They're *bit-flags*; you can set them individually, or none at all.

```
GLX_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB, GLX_CONTEXT_DEBUG_BIT_ARB,
```

This means to create a debug context.

```
    GLX_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB, GLX_CONTEXT_DEBUG_BIT_ARB | GLX_CONTEXT_ROBUST_ACCESS_BIT_ARB,
```

This means to create a debug context that also uses [robust access](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/glx_create_context_robustness.txt) (I use this example rather than your forward compatibility one because you should *never use forward compatibility*). They're bit-flags; you bitwise or them together.

```
    GLX_CONTEXT_FLAGS_ARB, 0,
```

This means no flags. So it won't be a debug context, it won't use robust access, etc. That's probably what you are looking for.

Also, you can choose not to pass flags at all.

Comment: Could you expend on "robust access" usage?I read the docs but haven't really understood why I would need it.Or I should submit this as another question ? ;)

Comment: @MichaelIV: Robust access has been introduced only recently to aid the development of OpenGL frameworks or backends executing untrusted code, like WebGL in the browser for example. Prior to the robust access methods, certain OpenGL methods could be used to leak information from other processes or be used for code injection. With robust features enabled, certain additional sanity checks are added and also no uninitialized buffers left. For details see http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/robustness.txt